# Why is the FBLogin not working in simulator ? - It stays in Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, safari

I am using xcode 7.3.And the latest version of fb sdk.I did all method declaration as per the Fb Documentation.But now when i press login with facebook button.It redirect to safari page and its asking whether you want to allow.I gave Yes.After that it still in safari page.And here is one "Done "Button at top left corner of safari page know.If i press that done button only its going in to my home screen.I dont know why?

I tries resetting my simulator, And adding all needed thing in info.plist.But its not working.I am having fb, google plus both login button.But this fb is not working.

Any solution would be great

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here after i press the done button only its allowing me to go inside the app.( home screen ).

**My code in appdelegate :**

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }


    func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

       // let GoogleHandler = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

        let FacebookHandler = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

        return  FacebookHandler
    }
```

My code in viewcontroller :

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate,  FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
{
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
            print("User Already Logged In")
        }
        else
        {
            print("User Not Logged In")
        }

        fbLoginBtn.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        fbLoginBtn.center = self.view.center
        fbLoginBtn.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(fbLoginBtn)
}

    ////// ------- Fb login delegate methods ------ //////

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
    {
        if error == nil
        {
            print("Login complete.")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                let appdelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                _ = appdelegate.window!.rootViewController


                let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let mainViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

                let leftViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController


                let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)

                let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)


                let centerContainer:MMDrawerController = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)



                centerContainer.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

                centerContainer.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

                               appdelegate.centerContainer = centerContainer

                appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = appdelegate.centerContainer

                appdelegate.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

        }
        else
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
    {
        print("User logged out...")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works with XCode 7.3. When you logged from facebook, it come back on your view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Login steps
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
    {
        // User is not already logged
        print("Not logged")
    }
    else
    {
        // User is already logged
        print("Logged")
    }
}

// Facebook Delegate Methods
func loginButton(connection: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("Error")
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }
        print("User logged in")
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User Logged Out")
}
```

Comment: so inside this statement ` if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }` I have to do the navigation to my home screen.Right??

Comment: Any solution please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251141/swipe-left-or-right-to-load-the-view-controller-with-the-collection-view-cell-hi

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding this AppDelegate method:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed
    return wasHandled;
}
```

Sorry for the Objective-C answer, I just copied it from my project. But you should be able to get the point.

Comment: Any solution please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251141/swipe-left-or-right-to-load-the-view-controller-with-the-collection-view-cell-hi

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to add one method in Appdelegate as below

```
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Second this is due to ios version it will have some problems with ios 9 and above so it will work fine in device as well.

Comment: again its still in my safari page.

Comment: have you tested in device?

Comment: send me your demo project using tinyupload i will test and let you know @spikesa

Comment: okay.I also have one doubt.How can i get the logged user name ,password, profile pic, all in ..I mean to print in console

Comment: Because , user is logged in but still in safari page.And also i am asking , how to get the logged user email, password, profile pic in my fb delegate method ...As per my above code

Comment: Like this "print("Gmail Successful Login.")
            let sEmail = user.profile.email
            let sPassword = user.userID"

Comment: This is for gmail.Like wise how can i get the logged user user gmail, password, profile pic, location ??